# Migration is required due to the following errors: - Property 'ToDoItem.id' has been made required

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I updated the Realm plugin to 10.15.1 and I got the following error even though my class hasn't changed.

**Migration is required due to the following errors:
- Property 'ToDoItem.id' has been made required.**

How do I migrate something that hasn't changed.

```
open class ToDoItem : RealmObject() {
    @PrimaryKey
    private var id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    var text: String = ""
    var colour: String = ""
    var isDone: Boolean = false
    var isTitle: Boolean = false
    var isImportant: Boolean = false

    fun getId(): String {
        return id
    }
}
```

In response to @Jay comment I tried updating the schema like so but got the same error.

```
val config = RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .schemaVersion(2)
            .build()
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config)
```

The Realm documentation has the code below but how do I instantiate the property schema?

```
val schema = RealmSchema() ???
    val config = RealmConfiguration.Builder(
            schema = setOf(ToDoItem::class)
    )
            .schemaVersion(2)
            .build()
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config)
```

Comment: Hmm. Odd error. Has the id *ever* changed? Are you using any kind of migration currently? If so, can you try incrementing the schema version?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jay I worked it out.
I told the new schema that ToDoItem.id is now required.

```
Realm.init(this)
val config = RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .schemaVersion(1)
            .migration(RealMigrations())
            .build()
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config)

class RealMigrations: RealmMigration {
override fun migrate(realm: DynamicRealm, oldVersion: Long, newVersion: Long) {
    val schema = realm.schema
    if (oldVersion == 0.toLong()) {
        schema.get("ToDoItem")?.setRequired("id", true)
    }
}
```

}